# How do I create a customized Ubuntu Live CD?

Tags: live-cd, customizer

I am trying to build a customized Ubuntu based Live CD. My purpose it to have Ubuntu based installable ISO within minimum required packages including GUI plus additional VLC, and PDF reader packages in it.

After searching the web I found following 2 ways to prepare Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD,

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

I could have been able to create Live CD from both of the above options. But I am facing some problem in both option to achieve my purpose:

- Following the first link, everything was fine except the installer, which is text-based instead of graphical. I was unable to add grub2, plymouth-x11 and ubiquity-frontend-gtk.
- Following the second link I wasn't able to remove unneeded packages.

What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at [Live CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Ubuntu Builder](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder)

> Ubuntu Builder is a simple tool to create your own distribution. It allows to download, extract, customize in many ways and rebuild the ubuntu images. You can customize i386 and amd64 desktop ISO images.